# java version in linux

Tags: java, linux, classpath

```
# which java
/usr/bin/which: no java in (/usr/local/jdk/jdk1.5.0_10/bin/java:/usr/local/jdk/jdk1.5.0_10/bin:/usr/kerberos/sbin:/usr/kerberos/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin)
```

I installed java in /usr/local/jdk/jdk1.5.0_10 but cannot run java -version

I get this

```
$ java -version
-bash: /usr/bin/java: No such file or directory
```

this is red hat linux

Comment: Questions like this belong on "superuser.com" or some such.

Answer (score 3):

It's not in your path.

use

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/jdk/jdk1.5.0_10/bin

export JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/jdk/jdk1.5.0_10
```

Look at ~/.bash_profile for where to define this permanatly.

Comment: [root@server1  bin]# export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/jdk/jdk1.5.0_10/bin
[root@server1 bin]# export JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/jdk/jdk1.5.0_10
[root@server1 bin]# java
-bash: java: command not found
[root@server1 bin]# java -version
-bash: java: command not found

Comment: @ttommy851  You have problems with your $PATH setting.  Within your jdk there is a bin directory. Within that directory is the "java" executible.  That is the "java" that you are not finding.  Navigate to that directory and type "ls", you should see the java file.  Type "./java", you should see some output of some kind.  If you type "echo $PATH" you'll see what your path is set to, you probably need to adjust that.

Answer (score 0):

Can you do
`ls /usr/local/jdk/jdk1.5.0_10/bin`
And why is `/usr/local/jdk/jdk1.5.0_10/bin/java` in your path?

Comment: # ls /usr/java
ls: /usr/java: No such file or directory

Comment: # ls /usr/local/jdk/jdk1.5.0_10/bin
ls: /usr/local/jdk/jdk1.5.0_10/bin: No such file or directory

Comment: And why is /usr/local/jdk/jdk1.5.0_10/bin/java in your path?

I added it just to see if it works. Shall I remove it?

Comment: Java isn't installed where you think it is (/usr/local/jdk...). Try looking in /usr/java/jdk1.5.0_10 instead.

Answer (score 0):

Must be in local path of java before running to see what version is installed. Use find / -name java (this will list anything with java on the server copy the path ). path should end with..../jre/bin/java
copy full path.

Open Java location of the path you copied above, remove java at the end you path then enter, 
Enter command below:
./Java -Version